# Match dates and hour using Python Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex

I want to match dates and hours that have the following format:

```
17/05/2009 8:15
17/5/2009 08:15
17.05.2009 8:15
17-05-2009 8:15
17/05/2009 8:15:00

pat = "^([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[./-]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$"
```

I have used this pattern right now but it doesn't include the hour format. How can I write both date formats and time formats in this pattern at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: _I have used this pattern right now but it doesn't include the hour format._ That pattern doesn't look it contains anything to match the hours, no? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: I already wanted to add the hour format to the pattern and I said the pattern doesn't include the hour format. Thanks

Comment: It was a bit ambiguous, I was unsure. In any case, can you clarify what exactly the issue is? Are you familiar with regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a mandatory time in your format, you could use:

```
^([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[.\/-]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[.\/-]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})\s+([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d)(:[0-5]?\d)?$
```

If you want the time to be optional, you could use:

```
^([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[.\/-]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[.\/-]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})(\s+([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d)(:[0-5]?\d)?)?$
```

Of course capture groups can be changed depending on what data you need to extract, if any.

That being said, I would recommend a date library to handle things like this is most cases, although sometimes you might want regex e.g. for form validation in frameworks that only accept regex.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, the regular expression that I want to mention exactly.

Comment: As you said yes, the date library may be more useful.

Answer (score 2):

That regex pattern is a bit hard to read, which is going to make it hard to extend.  I might suggest using `datetime.strptime` instead:

```
from datetime import datetime

dates = [
  '17/05/2009 8:15',
  '17/5/2009 08:15',
  '17.05.2009 8:15',
  '17-05-2009 8:15',
  '17/05/2009 8:15:00',
]

def parse_date(date: str) -> datetime:
    for fmt in [
        "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M",
        "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M",
        "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M",
        "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S",
    ]:
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(date, fmt)
        except ValueError:
            continue
    raise ValueError(f"Couldn't parse '{date}'!")

datetimes = [parse_date(date) for date in dates]
```

With this approach it's easy to add new `fmt` strings, and easy to catch holes since you'll get a `ValueError` any time you input a date that doesn't conform to any of these formats.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The information you provided about datetime.strptime has been very helpful and useful.